# Make a timer in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a timer in jQuery and after the timer end (time = 0) one-button becomes appear, where is my problem ??

```html
<style>
  .btn_repeat {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

my body

```html
<p>
  You'll be automatically redirected in <span id="count">5</span> seconds...
</p>

<button class="btn_repeat">resend</button>
```

j query code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    (function() {
      var counter = 5;

      setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        if (counter >= 0) {
          span = document.getElementById("count");
          span.innerHTML = counter;
        }
        // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
        if (counter === 0) {
          clearInterval(counter);
          $(".btn_repeat").display = "block";
        }
      }, 1000);
    })();
  };
</script>
```

Comment: my j query code

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix jQuery and native JavaScript methods. Use [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) to display a hidden element.

```
$('.btn_repeat').show();
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method to set CSS properties of elements.

```
$('.btn_repeat').css("display", "block");
```